# Codename one - Dragging connected Lines together

Tags: java, codenameone

I am working on project where two or more lines are connected to each other at right angles with either x or y co-ordinate common in it. (I am using two different arrayList to store a starting point and then drawing a line). Now, while dragging the parent line, I'm updating the new point into arrayList, but I cann't keep the connected line drag along with it. Does anyone help me with this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand the problem since it's too specific to what you are doing, it's unclear what you used to drag the lines so obviously I don't understand what you mean by connecting them.

Comment: I am using a list to update the line when the pointer dragged is called and I am repainting it. This works when I am dragging one line at a time. But when I join 2 lines I am unable to drag both lines simultaneously. Is there a way to drag both lines at a same time.

Comment: I fail to see the portion related to Codename One in the question, you are asking something that is too specific to your application and assume familiarity with your app logic.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog It is not specific to my application. I want to know the functionality of pointerdragged() to drag multiple lines simultaneously. Do we have anything in the codenameone samples which explains the particular functionality?

Answer (score 0):

To use multi-touch just override in `Form` or in your focusable component the method `pointerDragged(int[] x, int[] y)`.